# Jquery help on selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I have this code that I can't modify, and I want to add a selector that selects (on click) all the elements under it, till the next appearance of the main element. The problem is they are not nested, just one under other.

```
<div class="project name">..</div>
<div data-project-id="1987" class="sidebar_project">...</div>
<div data-project-id="3087" class="sidebar_project">...</div>
<div data-project-id="8903" class="sidebar_project">...</div>
<div data-project-id="223570" class="sidebar_project">...</div> 
<div class="project name">..</div>
<div data-project-id="1846" class="sidebar_project">...</div>
<div data-project-id="0935" class="sidebar_project">...</div>
<div data-project-id="84735" class="sidebar_project">...</div> 
<div class="project name">..</div>
<div data-project-id="11135" class="sidebar_project">...</div>
```

I can easy select all sidebar_projects and hide them, but what I want its be able to make a button that on click hides/shows all sidebar_projects from It's project name div to the next project name div.

THx

Comment: Does `class="project name"` mean those divs will actually have different classes with the names of different projects? You can't add a common class to them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.project.name').on('click', function(e){
    $(this).nextUntil('.project.name', '.sidebar_project').toggle();
});
```

I didn't test this, but I think that this will be work fine for you.

More about `nextUntil()` see [here](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a little something like this:

```
$('div:not(.sidebar_project)').click(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil(':not(.sidebar_project)').toggle();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/6gMnr/2/

This assumes that my comment above was correct, i.e., the heading elements don't have the classes "project" and "name", but actually they have different classes with the names of different projects, thus making it necessary to select them on the basis of their *not* having the "sidebar_project" class.

Obviously the problem with this is that you might have other divs on the page, so I hope the divs shown in your question are within some containing object such that you can do this:

```
var $container = $("selector for container here");
$container.find('div:not(.sidebar_project)').click(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil(':not(.sidebar_project)').toggle();
});
```